# Pegar a url e alterar valor?

Tags: javascript, funções, url

Nó site tenho uma função para ordenar maior e menor valor. Preciso pegar a url atual e alterar um valor que esta dentro dela.

URL Atual: http://localhost/busca.php?tipo=locacao&ordem=vx&tim%5B%5D=Casa&bar%5B%5D=BRASIL&pagina=1

Preciso pegar o valor ordem=vx e mudar para ordem=v, e preciso fazer isso dentro dessa função abaixo. Pois é ela que faz ação.

```
$("#sort-type").change(function() {

            var url = window.location.href;

            $("#order").val( $(this).val() )
            $("#formFilter").submit();
        });
```

Como posso fazer isso dentro dessa função?

Comment: Essa url é da sua página?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como o [colega](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/35406/viana) disse, existe várias formas de se obter esse valor. De acordo com essa [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42353290/6754506) pode ser conforme segue

Para pegar o valor você pode usar assim:

```
let searchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)
```

Pegar o valor assim:

```
let order = searchParams.get('ordem')
```

E então fazer o que você quer

Fonte:

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams

Answer (score 0):

Tem algumas formas de fazer isso. Você pode criar uma função para dar um *replace* na sua URL atual, passando como parâmetro a própria URL, o nome do parâmetro e o valor que você deseja colocar nela. Este exemplo está aqui [nesta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20420424/2570426) do SOen. Veja abaixo um exemplo:

```js
function replaceParam(url, paramName, paramValue)
{
    if (paramValue == null) {
        paramValue = '';
    }
    var pattern = new RegExp('\\b('+paramName+'=).*?(&|#|$)');
    if (url.search(pattern)>=0) {
        return url.replace(pattern,'$1' + paramValue + '$2');
    }
    url = url.replace(/[?#]$/,'');
    return url + (url.indexOf('?')>0 ? '&' : '?') + paramName + '=' + paramValue;
}

var url = window.location.href;

console.log(replaceParam(url, "ordem", "v"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Crie uma função utilitária que usa as APIs Web [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) e [URLSearchParam](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams). Essas APIs funcionam em todos os navegadores, exceto possivelmente Internet Explorer (para variar). O exemplo abaixo pode ser usado em qualquer local e tem o seguinte comportamento:

- se o parâmetro não existe, então o insere ao final
- se existem vários parâmetros (repetidos), então todos eles são deletados e apenas um é substituído

```js
function changeParam(url, param, value) {
    const urlObject = new URL(url)
    const urlSearchParams = urlObject.searchParams
    urlSearchParams.set(param, value)

    return urlObject.href
}

const tests = [
  {
      href: 'http://localhost/busca.php?tipo=locacao&ordem=vx&tim%5B%5D=Casa&bar%5B%5D=BRASIL&pagina=1',
      param: 'ordem',
      value: 'valor do parâmetro "ordem"'
  },
  {
      href: 'http://www.example.com.br/foo/bar.php?q1=arg1&q2=arg2&q1=3#hash',
      param: 'q1',
      value: 'newQ1'
  },
  {
      href: window.location.href,
      param: 'nao_existe',
      value: 'não existe ainda'
  },
]

tests.forEach(({href, param, value}) => {
    console.log(changeParam(href, param, value))
})
```